# Unable to save an ImageBuffer: no method named `save` found

Tags: image, rust

I am trying to save an [`ImageBuffer`](https://docs.rs/image/0.12.3/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html) to a file, but I am having some trouble getting types to agree:

```
extern crate image;

use image::{ImageBuffer, Pixel, Rgb};

fn main() {
    let img = ImageBuffer::new(256, 256);

    for x in 0..256 {
        for y in 0..256 {
            let pixel = Rgb::from_channels(0, x ^ y, 0, 0);
            img.put_pixel(x, y, pixel);
        }
    }

    img.save("output.png");
}
```

Which produces the following compiler error:

```
error: no method named `save` found for type `image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgb<u32>, std::vec::Vec<u32>>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
15 |     img.save("output.png");
   |         ^^^^
```

I believe the type of pixel isn't matching up with the definition required for [`save` seen in the docs](https://docs.rs/image/0.12.3/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html#method.save).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up needing to do some type conversion to get the signatures to agree.

Here is the working code:

```
extern crate image;

use image::{ImageBuffer, Pixel, Rgb};

fn main() {
    let mut img = ImageBuffer::new(256, 256);

    for x in 0..256 {
        for y in 0..256 {
            let pixel = Rgb::from_channels(0, x as u8 ^ y as u8, 0, 0);
            img.put_pixel(x as u32, y as u32, pixel);
        }
    }

    img.save("output.png");
}
```